# Get element and append to new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can not change the basic HTML of this page and the structure of it doesn't allow me to get and append some items i need. Here is the basic HTML

```
<table id="standings">
 <caption><span>League</span></caption>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td id="division00"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td class="fname">
        <img src="/UR1.png">
      </td>

    </tr>

   <tr>
      <td class="fname">
        <img src="/UR2.png">
      </td>

   </tr>


   <tr>
    <td id="division01"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td class="fname">
        <img src="/UR3.png">
      </td>

   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td class="fname">
        <img src="/UR4.png">
      </td>

   </tr>


   <tr>
    <td id="division02"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td class="fname">
        <img src="/UR5.png">
      </td>

   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td class="fname">
        <img src="/UR6.png">
      </td>

   </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to pull the td.fname img in td#division00 and place in another location on the page, but due to the html layout , the td id for divsion00 does not wrap the contents of the table that include the assigned fname for each divsion. I have tried this, but does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#standings #divsion00 td.fname').appendTo('#newdiv');
});
</script>
```

When i use a more general setting like below i get all the td.fname images , but i only wish to get the ones listed for each division separately. Anyone know of a way to pull just the group listed under each #division00 , #division01 , #division02

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#standings td.fname').appendTo('#newdiv');
});
</script>
```

Comment: You realize you don't have a `divsiion00` element, there's an `i` too many ?

Comment: `$('#division00').closest('tr').next('tr').find('.fname')`

Comment: There are two rows after the division row that have an image. Do you want to move both of the images, or just the first? If both, will there always be two or can the number vary?

Comment: ty adeneo i mistyped that and corrected in my post. I want to move all images for each division , the fnames and images are dynamically created by the host site from another script , so there are sometimes up to 10 images for each #division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#division00").parent().next().find('.fname img').appendTo("#newdiv");
```

if `#newdiv` doesn't exist and you want to create a new div:

```
var newdiv = $('<div>');
$("#division00").parent().next().find('.fname img').appendTo(newdiv);
newdiv.appendTo("body"); // Or wherever you want
```

If you need all images for the division:

```
$("#division00").parent().nextAll().each(function(){
   if($(this).children("td[id^=division]").length) return false;
   $(this).find('.fname img').appendTo("#newdiv");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9wU7Y/

Comment: inserted that and would not find the fname images , i already have the new div added btw and thanks

Comment: strange, it works for me in the fiddle. Oh well, feel free to accept the other answer if that one worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

This function should get all the image rows for a given division ID:

```
function getImageRows(divisionId) {
    var $divisionRow = $('#' + divisionId).closest('tr');

    var $imageRows = $();
    for ($row = $divisionRow.next(); $row.length > 0; $row = $row.next()) {
        if ($row.find('.fname').length > 0) {
            $imageRows = $imageRows.add($row);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $imageRows;
}
```

You can then move the `<img>` elements for a division like this:

```
var $imageRows = getImageRows('division00');
$imageRows.find('img').appendTo('#newDiv');
```

You can then remove the now empty rows like this:

```
$imageRows.remove();
```